# getting the max value of 3 tags with xquery (oracle)

Tags: oracle, max, xquery

i have to combine some xml documents with xquery on a oracle 10.2 db.

therefore i need to get the max value of some tags:

i've tried this:

```
   fn:max(( $p/col_1, $p/col_3 ))
```

the xml input (variable $p) is:

```
   <xml_snippet>
      <col_1>123</col_1>
      <col_2>123</col_2>
      <col_3>123</col_3>
    </xml_snippet>
```

but i've got an error message

```
  ORA-19112: error raised during evaluation: oracle.xquery.XQException: FORG0001: invalid value for cast/constructor
```

how can i get the maximum value only of col_1 and col_3?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try GREATEST instead of MAX?

Comment: something like: "for $i in $p order by $i greatest" ? (pseudocode) how can i check only some of the tags in xml_snippet with this? i have to skip "col_2" and some other tags

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with XQuery in Oracle, but, given the error message, I would suggest that you cast the values to integers:

```
let $values :=
  for $x in ( $p/col_1, $p/col_3 )
  return xs:integer($x)
return fn:max($values)
```